# reactjs is not picking up style from index.css

Tags: reactjs

it seems like my react Application is not picking up the style from index.css file. Would someone please let me know what could be the reason.

I have index.css as mentioned below.

```
body{
  background-color: aqua
}
```

> however, I don't see aqua colour of any of the page.

Comment: how r u importing the css?

Comment: @andresmijares Thanks, I put the following the line in my app.js and it resolved the issue `import './index.css'`

Comment: Can you post your code , Make sure there is no other body tag style which is overwriting this.